# Order a vector of text strings

Tags: r, string

I have a vector of text strings in the object `imgs`. They only differ by the percentage expression in the string. For example, the string representing 5% is named `stress_test_results_5pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png`, where `_5pct_` in the string corresponds to 5%. I have 17 strings in the vector and I would like to ensure the order beginning at 5% and ending at 85% is maintained.

data:

```
c("stress_test_results_10pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_15pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_20pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_25pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_30pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_35pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_40pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_45pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_50pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_55pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_5pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_60pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_65pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_70pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_75pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_80pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png", 
"stress_test_results_85pct_ar_uncollectable_small_grain_cooperatives.png"
)
```

Comment: The easiest -and most consistent- solution is to add a leading 0, so change `_5pct_` to `_05pct_`.

Comment: `stringr::str_sort(your_vector, numeric = TRUE)`

Comment: x[match(sort(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]+", "", x, perl = T))), as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]+", "", x, perl = T)))]

Comment: @Snipeskies  `x[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D+","", x)))]` is what you are looking for